# Python - how to fill a pygame screen from a different method

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am trying to have a reset button in my tkinter form for a program that uses pygame.

The reset button must reset the pygame screen, which means filling it in with one colour, which in my case is black.

I will not show the full code as it is long, but snippets.

```
btn_reset = Button(simFrame)
    btn_reset.config(text = "Reset", borderwidth = 2, padx = 0, pady=0, width = 8)
    btn_reset.bind("<Button-1>", self.reset) #left click to acvtivate
    btn_reset.grid(row = 8, column = 0, sticky = W)
```

The button activates 'self.reset', which is the method I am trying to fill the screen from (if there is a way to fill the screen within the method that pygame is in let me know, I am new to tkinter/pygame and only know how to start a method from a button).

```
def reset(self, event):
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.update()
```

This is what I want to do, obviously this doesn't work.

The screen has already been made in another method, how do I fill it from this one?

Or even better, can I fill the screen from within the pygame method when activating the button?

EDIT:

```
def display(self):
    #moving variables from method to method
    megatonVar = self.megatonVar
    locationVar = self.locationVar
    populationVar = self.populationVar

    #resets circle widths
    locCircleWidth = 2
    fireCircleWidth = 2
    air20CircleWidth = 2
    radCircleWidth = 2
    air5CircleWidth = 2
    thermCircleWidth = 2

    constantK = (float(megatonVar)) ** (1/3) #creates a constant variable that can be used later

    #does blast radius equations using the megaton input to calculate the blast radius'
    #R = K x cuberoot(Y)
    #R = radius  K = constant  Y = yield
    locCircleRadius = (locationVar) / 1
    fireCircleRadius = 0.0912 * (constantK)
    radCircleRadius = 0.3683 * (constantK)
    thermCircleRadius = 0.9910 * (constantK)
    air20CircleRadius = 0.2182 * (constantK)
    air5CircleRadius = 0.4545 * (constantK)

    #calculate population affected
    #population affected by blast radius
    if (air5CircleRadius / locCircleRadius) >= 1:
        self.popBlastValue.set("%.2f" %(populationVar))
    else:
        self.popBlastValue.set("%.2f" %((air5CircleRadius / locCircleRadius)*(populationVar)))
    #population affected by radiation radius
    if (thermCircleRadius / locCircleRadius) >= 1:
        self.popRadValue.set("%.2f" %(populationVar))
    else:
        self.popRadValue.set("%.2f" %((thermCircleRadius / locCircleRadius)*(populationVar)))

    pygame.init()                                #initialises pygame
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,900))  #creates pygame display  (x, y)
    screen.fill(black)                           #clears screen

    #updates the text displaying the screen scale depending on scale
    if (locCircleRadius >= 20) or (thermCircleRadius >= 20):
        screenScale = "60km"
    elif (locCircleRadius > 10 and locCircleRadius < 20) or (thermCircleRadius > 10 and thermCircleRadius < 20):
        screenScale = "40km"
    else:
        screenScale = "20km"

    #draws scale line
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (0, 35, 800, 2)) #x, y, w, h

    #adds increments to scale depending on size
    if (locCircleRadius >= 20) or (thermCircleRadius >= 20):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (66, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (133, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (201, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (268, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (334, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (400, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (467, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (534, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (601, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (667, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (734, 35, 2, 10))
    elif (locCircleRadius > 10 and locCircleRadius < 20) or (thermCircleRadius > 10 and thermCircleRadius < 20):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (100, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (200, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (300, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (400, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (500, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (600, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (700, 35, 2, 10))            
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (200, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (400, 35, 2, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (600, 35, 2, 10))

    #scales the screen with radius      
    if (locCircleRadius >= 20) or (thermCircleRadius >= 20):
        locCircleRadius *= 10
        fireCircleRadius *= 10
        radCircleRadius *= 10
        thermCircleRadius *= 10
        air20CircleRadius *= 10
        air5CircleRadius *= 10
    elif (locCircleRadius > 10 and locCircleRadius < 20) or (thermCircleRadius > 10 and thermCircleRadius < 20):
        locCircleRadius *= 20
        fireCircleRadius *= 20
        radCircleRadius *= 20
        thermCircleRadius *= 20
        air20CircleRadius *= 20
        air5CircleRadius *= 20
    else:
        locCircleRadius *= 40
        fireCircleRadius *= 40
        radCircleRadius *= 40
        thermCircleRadius *= 40
        air20CircleRadius *= 40
        air5CircleRadius *= 40

    #if the circle radius is smaller than the width pygame gives an error,
    #so the width must become lower than the radius if radius is lower than width
    if locCircleRadius < locCircleWidth:
        locCircleWidth = (locCircleRadius - 0.1)

    if fireCircleRadius < fireCircleWidth:
        fireCircleWidth = (fireCircleRadius - 0.1)

    if air20CircleRadius < air20CircleWidth:
        air20CircleWidth = (air20CircleRadius - 0.1)

    if radCircleRadius < radCircleWidth:
        radCircleWidth = (radCircleRadius - 0.1)

    if air5CircleRadius < air5CircleWidth:
        air5CircleWidth = (air5CircleRadius - 0.1)

    if thermCircleRadius < thermCircleWidth:
        thermCircleWidth = (thermCircleRadius - 0.1)

    #draws the circles on the pygame display.   (colour, (x,y midpoint), radius, width)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (400,500), int(locCircleRadius), int(locCircleWidth))              #location - white
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, orange, (400,500), int(fireCircleRadius), int(fireCircleWidth))           #fireball - orange
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, lightGreen, (400,500), int(radCircleRadius), int(radCircleWidth))         #radiation - light green
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, lightOrange, (400,500), int(thermCircleRadius), int(thermCircleWidth))    #thermalradiation - light orange
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (400,500), int(air20CircleRadius), int(air20CircleWidth))            #airblast20psi - red
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, grey, (400,500), int(air5CircleRadius), int(air5CircleWidth))             #airblast5psi - grey

    #initialize font; must be called after 'pygame.init()' to avoid 'Font not Initialized' error
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("courier", 20)

    #render text
    widthLabel = myfont.render(("Screen width = {}".format(screenScale)), 1, white)
    screen.blit(widthLabel, (10, 10))
    scaleLabel = myfont.render(("Scale increment = 5km"), 1, white)
    screen.blit(scaleLabel, (540, 10))

    #updates the display so the circles are shown
    pygame.display.update()
```

Welp. Since you wanted it, here is where the screen is made. Has a lot of irrelevant stuff, but you cant see it. I didn't see the point in showing that I had actually created a screen. Also at this point there is no error, I just don't know how to fill the pygame method by pressing a tkinter button.

Comment: What is the error?  Is is simply that `screen` is not in the method's scope?  Where is `screen` created?

Comment: It is not entirely clear where screen here is defined.. please provide a MVE

Comment: Added code where screen is created.

Comment: And I fixed it anyway. Sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

```
#button - reset
    btn_reset = Button(simFrame)
    btn_reset.config(text = "Reset", borderwidth = 2, padx = 0, pady=0, width = 8)
    btn_reset.bind("<Button-1>", self.reset) #left click to acvtivate
    btn_reset.grid(row = 8, column = 0, sticky = W)
```

is button

```
def display(self):
    pygame.init()                                #initialises pygame
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,900))  #creates pygame display  (x, y)
    self.screen = screen
    screen.fill(black)                           #clears screen

def reset(self, event):
    (self.screen).fill(black)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [`pygame.display.get_surface`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.get_surface):

> **pygame.display.get_surface()**
>   *Get a reference to the currently set display surface*
>   `get_surface() -> Surface`
>
> Return a reference to the currently set display Surface. If no display mode has been set this will return None.

to get the screen surface.